# rendering Rust turtle in headless environment

Tags: rust, turtle-graphics, video-capture, rust-cargo

Is there a way to render the following Rust [turtle](https://crates.io/crates/turtle) drawing in a headless environment?

I'm interested in both exporting the final result to an image file, and the drawing process itself to a video file.

My `main.rs` looks like this

```
use turtle::Turtle;

fn main() {
    let mut turtle = Turtle::new();

    for _ in 0..360 {
        // Move forward three steps
        turtle.forward(3.0);
        // Rotate to the right (clockwise) by 1 degree
        turtle.right(1.0);
    }
}
```

`Cargo.toml` looks like this

```
[package]
name = "doodle" # the name of the package
version = "0.1.0"    # the current version
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
turtle = "1.0.0-rc.3"

# Compile turtle and other dependencies with optimizations
[profile.dev.package."*"]
opt-level = 3
```

`Dockerfile` looks like this

```
FROM rust:latest

WORKDIR /usr/src/doodle
COPY ./src .

CMD cargo run
```

When running the container I'm getting the following error:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'Failed to initialize any backend! Wayland status: XdgRuntimeDirNotSet X11 status: LibraryOpenError(OpenError { kind: Library, detail: "opening library failed (libXcursor.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory); opening library failed (libXcursor.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)" })', /usr/local/cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/winit-0.19.5/src/platform/linux/mod.rs:467:9

note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, that would have to be something that the developers would need to add in. Looking through the source code, the GUI window is created whenever `Turtle::new()` is called, so there isn't a way to start the drawing without needing the window.

It looks like the devs are still working on it though (last commit is less than a month old), so you may try posting an issue on their [github](https://github.com/sunjay/turtle) mentioning that a feature that allows you to output to a file instead of drawing to the window could be useful.